# Circular HTML shape - only DIV works, but I want it inline

Tags: html, css

I want a matte circular shape with a thin border around it, like this:

```css
.circle {
  height: 1.5em;
  width: 1.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0.1em;
}

.ci {
  margin: 0.2em;
  height: 1.1em;
  width: 1.1em;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
Bang:
<div class="circle">
  <div class="ci"></div>
</div> More
```

but it needs to be inline, i.e. no line break after 'Bang:' and no line break before 'More'. If I exchange the `div`s for `span`s or say `display: inline` for the divs, the shape is gone.

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GK4AJ5M28W16

Comment: Have you tried `inline-block`?

Comment: Answered in the comments lol.

Comment: @N-ate This question doesn’t need its own answer, if a duplicate target can be found, which it probably can be for this question.

Comment: Well I feel there has been a legit effort on the side of OP here so I thought a little bit of help with a basic flexbox setup would allow him/her to continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use flexbox positioning like this:

```css
.circle {
  height: 1.5em;
  width: 1.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0.1em;
}

.ci {
  margin: 0.2em;
  height: 1.1em;
  width: 1.1em;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

section {
display:flex;align-items:center;
}

section * {
margin:0 10px;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex">
<span>Bang:</span>
<div class="circle"><div class="ci"></div></div>
<span>Bang:</span>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `display: inline-block;` for the shape, border-radius etc. to work, and add `vertical-align: middle;` for an appropriate alignment:

```css
.circle {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 1.5em;
  width: 1.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0.1em;
}

.ci {
  margin: 0.2em;
  height: 1.1em;
  width: 1.1em;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
Bang:
<div class="circle">
  <div class="ci"></div>
</div> More
```